# How do I make a file downloadable in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I need help on frontend

Following is how I am sending files to blade

```
$files = Storage::disk('local')->allFiles('init/'.$id);

return view('view_name',['files'=>$files]);
```

Following is how I handling on frontend

```
@foreach($files as $file)
<a href="{{ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::url(basename($file)) }}" download>{{basename($file) }}</a>
@endforeach
```

when I click on the link I see "Failed - No file" error.

I am trying this from couple of days now, it seems am stuck. please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can Save file address in database and use this code :
$id :  , $file :

```
public function showFile($id,$file){

    $user= auth()->user();
    if(!$user->hasPermission($id))
        return abort(403);
    $file=str_replace(',','',$file);
    return response()->download(storage_path('../../domains/SITE.com/secureUp/aDoc/'.$id.'/'.$file), null, [], null);

}
```

Comment: is it necessary to save files in database, currently am saving locally on sever then I want move to AWS S3.

Answer (score 0):

The download method may be used to generate a response that forces the user's browser to download the file at the given path

```
return Storage::download('file.jpg');

return Storage::download('file.jpg', $name, $headers);
```

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question, need help on front end, how do i pass info to download method